# Windows 8 Calendar: not showing certain calendars on tiles; custom colours

Tags: windows, windows-8, calendar, google-calendar, windows-8-calendar-app

I'm presently syncing my Google calendars to the Windows 8 Calendar app, and despite the little things that still need to be worked on within the app, it works fine. I used the tip where you use an iPhone user agent to allow multiple calendars on Google's mobile website, and it works well. Syncs fast and all.

However, there is one issue. In Google (and also on Windows 8), my best friend and I share our calendars, so we can always know what the other is doing and whether she's available, etc. I just added hers to Windows recently.

So here. Now, her upcoming events also show up on the live tile, which I find is a pity, because as much as I like to be able to see what she's doing and when when I look at the calendar, I don't need to be reminded of when she works and such.

The live tile was great: I put it on large size, and it showed me upcoming events. So when I opened up the Start screen for whatever reason, I could see what I might have forgotten that's coming soon. But now, that's "polluted" with events of hers.

Is there a way to tell Calendar which calendars I want to display on the live tile, and which I don't?

Also, I'm wondering, is there a way to set a custom colour to a calendar? I always categorise mine between many categories, so I can easily see what is what. But there's a very low amount of colours available from the menu, and many are very similar (orange, mango, red, purple, raspberry... ._.).

On my phone, I put her calendar in grey, so when I'm looking at the calendar, I can know it's (probably) not important for me right now, while all of my events (class, work to hand in, work...) is in colour. But that colour isn't available in the Windows calendar. Actually, every single colour is flashy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Calendar Tiles". This an App specifically developed for this purpose.

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb/app/calendar-tiles/e9d098cc-20af-47af-a3a7-8503fb9d0a1c

Comment: please remember to state in your answer your role as person involved in the software mentioned.

Comment: This looks quite awesome... except that it doesn't seem to work with my Google calendars. It only sees my (empty/useless) Microsoft calendars. Well, I think they said already that because Google doesn't support the ActiveSync(?) technology anymore, Windows can't sync with them anymore. I'll go see if I can reverse the whole process (make my calendars Microsoft and have my phone use them) and I'll come back to you. I think I should head over to android.stackexchange.com for now~